# Can't repair NTFS disk on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ntfs, fsck

I tried to fsck a NTFS disk with gparted on my Ubuntu 16.04 and get the error message below which advices me to "Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!".
Now I have no Windows installation, I do, however, have a Windows virtual machine. Can I use it for the repair or is there any other way to accomplish the necessary repair?

Thanks in advance for any tip

H

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
Libparted 3.2
Kontrollera och reparera filsystemet (ntfs) på /dev/sdc1  00:00:14    ( FEL )
        
kalibrera /dev/sdc1  00:00:01    ( LYCKADES )
        
sökväg: /dev/sdc1 (partition)
start: 2048
slut: 1748721663
storlek: 1748719616 (833.85 GiB)
kontrollera filsystemet på /dev/sdc1 efter fel och korrigera dem (om möjligt)  00:00:13    ( FEL )
        
ntfsresize -i -f -v /dev/sdc1  00:00:13    ( FEL )
        
ntfsresize v2015.3.14AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sdc1
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 895344439808 bytes (895345 MB)
Current device size: 895344443392 bytes (895345 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
Cluster 171130245 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 171140480 is referenced multiple times!
100.00 percent completed
ERROR: Filesystem check failed!
ERROR: 2 clusters are referenced multiple times.
NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.
========================================**
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. You *need* MS Windows to maintain an ntfs volume. Do not use the nfts file format if you only have Ubuntu, and if you are not intending to connect the drive periodically to a Windows system, except if the data on the drive is discardable (I use an ntfs drive for my television, for example) and you are prepared to format now and then (it has been several years since I checked and reformatted my drive.

*Background*

ntfs remains a proprietary file format developed by Microsoft. While Linux has basic tools to check the ntfs file system, it does not have the capability of Windows tools to check the partitions, and thus may not be able to handle more serious problems with the file system.

Comment: +1; Do you know if Windows in a virtual machine can manage a file system in a partition in the host computer's drive?

Comment: I guess no: volumes on the host machine are connected to the VM through a network connection.

Comment: @sudodus nope. You need an actual install for this. Linux can do a lot but there is no 100% guaranteed support for Windows. By the way: it IS legal to download Windows from any source and use the --installer-- to fix the disk. The license you need to use Windows is for an actual install.

Comment: @Rinzwind It will be great if you could write a step by step answer for how to use the Windows installer USB/DVD to fix `ntfs` partitions for those with external hard drives factory formatted this way, but not Windows installation to fix them with.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, a clear explanation so not knowing of Rinzwind's trick I did the following:

Found an old Windows 7 DVD

Disconnected all drives but the faulty

Added an unused SSD and installed Windows 7 on it

Repaired the disk with Windows

Disconnected the SSD and reconnected all other drives and rebooted

(All this in order to avoid all dual boot issues with MBR, Grub etc.)
H